# Copy range to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, excel-2016

I'm super new at VBA, and I am trying to copy range from a closed Excel file to an active workbook without overriding the current pasted range.

This is on Excel 2016.

```
Sub GetDataFromWbs()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fso.Getfolder("C:\Path")
    Dim lastrow As Long

    For Each wbFile In fldr.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D12").Formula = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:c3").Formula  
                'here is where I would like to add +1 so my loop isn't overridden   
            Next 'ws
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next 'wbFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the range you want to copy over always `A1:C3` from each of the workbooks?

Comment: yes but the Range can change, I would want to do find but for now Range would do

Comment: Do you know SQL?

Comment: I do not, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this might be what you're looking for.  I added comments to the code to help explain it.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook                   'The workbook where information will be copied into
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")    'The worksheet where information will be copied into
    sFolder = "C:\Test\"                        'The folder path containing the xlsx files to copy from
    lRow = 1                                    'The starting row where information will be copied into

    'Adjust the folder path to ensure it ends with \
    If Right(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sFolder = sFolder & "\"

    'Get the first .xlsx file in the folder path
    sFile = Dir(sFolder & "*.xlsx")

    'Begin loop through each file in the folder
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0

        'Open the current workbook in the folder
        With Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile)
            'Copy over the formulas from A1:C3 from only the first worksheet into the destination worksheet
            Set rCopy = .Sheets(1).Range("A1:C3")
            wsDest.Cells(lRow, "A").Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count).Formula = rCopy.Formula

            'Advance the destination row by the number of rows being copied over
            lRow = lRow + rCopy.Rows.Count

            .Close False    'Close the workbook that was opened from the folder without saving changes
        End With
        sFile = Dir 'Advance to the next file
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is Amazing Thank you Tigeravatar.

one question if I want just the first sheet from the workbook instead each sheet from the wb?

Comment: @Spock See updated answer.  I removed the worksheet loop and instead only reference `Sheets(1)` of the opened workbook.

Comment: you are a lifesaver. Thank you much Tigeravatar

Comment: what if the files are in subfolder? sorry I should have mention that on my origianl post.

Comment: You mean, you have files in a main folder, and that main folder also has subfolders where you need to find files?  So all the files you need are spread out among multiple folders? If that's the case, I recommend asking a new question since that deviates significantly from the intent of this question.

Comment: you got it. Thank you. you have really helped me a lot.